# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rails-api'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with Rails 5.0.0.beta3 and creating a rails-api. when i run

```
rails-api generate scaffold user email:string password:string auth_token:string
```

it shows the error

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rails-api'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
from /home/ahsanul/Documents/rails-api/my_blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How can i resolve the problem?

Comment: `bundle install` in console

Comment: Not working. Same problem

Comment: have you tried `bundle update`?

Comment: yes. bundle update, bundle, same error @mtrolle

Comment: Could you show what your Gemfile looks like ?

Comment: Share your Gemfile. BTW, you don't need to include `rails-api` gem in your Rails 5 Gemfile. It's already merged into Rails 5.

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta3', '< 5.1'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'spring', :group => :development
gem 'mysql2'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to include `rails-api` gem in your Rails 5 app's Gemfile. It's already merged into Rails 5.

[Reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19832)

Comment: rails-api g scaffold user email:string password:string auth_token:string
and ommit gem 'rails-api'
Gem file look like
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta3', '< 5.1'
gem 'spring', :group => :development
gem 'mysql2'
and shoes the error: /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2157:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0xac89b0 rails-api-0.4.0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: I also run bundle update, bundle install and the above error

Comment: Remove `gem 'rails-api'` line from your Gemfile, and run `bundle`. It should be okay.

Comment: I did, remove the gem 'rails-api' line from my Gemfile and run bundle update, bundle install and also shows the error: /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2157:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0xac89b0 rails-api-0.4.0> (NoMethodError)
 from /home/ahsanul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1056:in `find_active_stub_by_path'

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above suggestion from Babar but didn't work, so i tried one little thing that work which is adding gem 'listen' to the gem file.
it works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

```
rails-api generate scaffold user email:string password:string auth_token:string
```

No need of writing rails-api, just use rails. Rails::API has been merged into Rails 5.0, so no need of gem 'rails-api'.So remove it from gemfile.After than you may get error when you try to migrate.So you have to include `listen` gem.